# Retrieving HTML metadata for image instead of downloading image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, cheerio

I am trying to use Cheerio with the Node.js request library to retrieve metadata about images. It looks like when I make an HTTP GET request to an URL that ends in .jpg, .png, etc, it will send back the whole file and I can't access the HTML in the response. So, my question is, given a URL to an image, how do I read just the HTML or metadata instead of downloading the whole image file upon making a request to the URL?

For example, here is some simple code I have:

```
    var request = require('request');
    var cheerio = require('cheerio'); // cheerio is just used to parse HTML on the server, like jquery for the server


    request('http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/content_index/images/sidekick_tv_news-2e9c408.png',function(err,response,body){

        var $ = cheerio.load(body);

        //here it seems like the body is not HTML but all the data pertaining to the image itself - I just want the typical HTML response, not a picture file


        });
```

does anyone know what I am talking about?

Comment: I can't understand, you are requesting an image file what kind of HTML you are supposed to receive?

Comment: You're requesting an image file so you're getting an image file. There is no html.

Comment: I want to get the html not just the image, so can I do that or not

Comment: hey did you able to solve it , i have same problem and don't know how to solve it..

Comment: I think there is a better way to do this, let me ask a friend of mine

Answer (score 1):

For starters you can use the image url in an img element:

```
var img = cheerio('<img src="' + imageUrl + '"></img>');
```

or

```
var img = cheerio.load('<img src="' + imageUrl + '"></img>');
```

Then you might be able to perform your queries